# Intellij/Datagrip query mongo by legacy uuid

Tags: mongodb, intellij-idea, datagrip

I'm trying to query `mongodb` from `intellij 2020.03` by `uuid` by I can't get my head over that. Can somebody please help me how to properly write the query for that?

I'm trying to search by this but that's not working at all.

```
db.tenant.find({_id: UUID('08933368-1cc5-4e09-8d75-07feca013214')});
```

**edit:** it's type 3 so probably legacy uuid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so after digging through some of the youtrack issues I found that it's needed to change the `uuidRepresentation` in connection settings to `javaLegacy` and mentioned query works now[image]